# Activerecord, 'foregin_key' has to be a combination of 2 fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, foreign-key-relationship

I want a has_many relationship described below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mcollections, :foreign_key=>'obj_id'
end
```

Below is definition of table mcollections

```
create table mcollections (
  id                     int            not null auto_increment,
  obj_id                 varchar(255)   not null,
  category               varchar(255)   not null,
);
```

The `:foreign_key` is NOT A SINGLE FIELD on table `mcollections`.  Foreign key has to be a combination of 2 fields (`obj_id + category`).  How can I specify this in `User` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the sense of using foreign keys here.
A foreign key should be the primary key of another table. Neither obj_id nor category could be used as foreign key because they are not part of the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do it another way?

Its not the best practice to use multi-column foreign keys in rails...